# Change path dynamically of $unwind expression in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say for example I have this data:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "checker": true,
    "app": "firstApp",
    "changes": [
        {
            "old": "testOld",
            "new": "testNew"
        },
        {
            "old": "firstAppOld",
            "new": "firstAppNew"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "checker": false,
    "app": "secondApp",
    "changes": ""
}
```

What I want is to $unwind this data dynamically. If *"checker"* = true, then {$unwind: "$changes"}, else {$unwind: "$app"}. Or if *"checker"* = true, then {$unwind: "$changes"}, else do nothing.

I tried adding a field:

```
{$addFields: {
        path: {
            $cond: {
                if: {$eq: ["$checker", true]},
                then: '$changes',
                else: '$app'
            }
        }
    }}
```

And then:

```
{$unwind: "$path"}
```

But I am getting something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "checker": true,
    "app": "firstApp",
    "changes": [
        {
            "old": "testOld",
            "new": "testNew"
        },
        {
            "old": "firstAppOld",
            "new": "firstAppNew"
        }
    ],
    "path": {
        "old": "testOld",
        "new": "testNew"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "checker": false,
    "app": "secondApp",
    "changes": "",
    "path": "secondApp"
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting? the property `app` is not an array.

Comment: So if app is a string, it wouldn't $unwind anything. This was for example. But what I want is the query to $unwind dynamically, using the "checker" field as a reference of an if clause.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, your condition is correct with checker field, what is the issue? what is the expected reuslt if it is not?

Comment: you can pass empty array blocks [] in the else part.

Answer (score 0):

The [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage takes a string path, not an expression, so you can't directly pass a variable to the stage.

However, you can modify the document prior to the unwind stage, such as:

- Use $cond in an $addFields stage to check the boolean to conditionally move the value to a temporary field
- $unwind the the temporary field
- Another $addFields stage to conditionally move the value back to the original field
- $project to remove the temporary field

Perhaps something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
    temparray: {
      $cond: {
        if: "$unwindit",
        then: "$array",
        else: "Nope"
      }
    }
  }},
  {$unwind: "$temparray"},
  {$addFields: {
    array: {
      $cond: {
        if: "$unwindit",
        then: "$temparray",
        else: "$array"
      }
    },  
  }},
  {$project: {temparray: 0}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p8r511nla8Y)